# Slow (wired) internet in terminal and software center Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: internet, connection, download-speed

New Ubuntu user here. I am dual booting with Windows 8.1, and in 8.1 I have no issues. In Ubuntu, I noticed extremely slow download speeds while downloading packages and it seems to also occur in the software center. For example, I just ran apt-get upgrade and downloaded a 15MB file in 5m @ 54.9KB/s. I haven't noticed browsing (in firefox) to be slow, and in fact speedtest.net returned similar results to what I see in Windows (~20MB down and 4.5MB up). I've read in some places where certain applications can cause internet to slow down, but I don't know if that is the case here. I've run the "host www.google.com" command that I've read other recommend and the results were returned very quickly. I am not sure if I actually have a problem (and if so how to diagnose and resolve) or if I'm having bad luck. One issue I experience when installing Ubuntu, which may or may not be related, is Ubuntu didn't seem to like any devices plugged into a certain sata controller (i.e. when plugged in, I could not boot to liveusb but when I unplugged it I could). I'm wondering if there's some chipset issue that is extending to what I am experiencing now. More likely, I have no idea what I'm talking about. Any help is appreciated.